# Extract select columns from file based on value in single column

Tags: bash, shell, awk

I have a text file with 9 columns. Column 1 contains values 1-22. I want to print a new file containing only rows where column 1 = 15. Can this be done using awk?

Comment: No attempted code, no sample data and no expected output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`awk` to the rescue!

```
awk '$1==15' file
```

assumes whitespace is the field delimiter, otherwise set -F (e.g. for csv `-F,`)